# Handlebars interpolation with element attribute?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have `model` which (beside other fields) have `id` field. Main question is how to do following: 
`<tr class="{{tableStripes id}}">` where `tableStripes` is helper defined as:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('tableStripes', function(index) {
    return (index % 2) ? "even" : "odd";
});
```

More interesting (for me) is final result in browser:

```
<tr class="<script id='metamorph-10-start' type='text/x-placeholder'></script>even<script id='metamorph-10-end' type='text/x-placeholder'></script>">
```

From where that comes? As i can see helpers returned good result ("even" between script tags).

Comment: is ```Ember.Handlebars.helper``` same as ```Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need to `unbound` that if you don't want it to inject the metamorph right into the class.  There is a caveat though, if you are changing data, unbound won't update and you'll want to look at the other possibility below

```
<tr class="{{unbound tableStripes id}}">
```

You could also mimic how the helper `bind-attr` does it: [bind-attr source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/e34bf4b17175af37c47219d0a93d21ecfc4bfda5/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/helpers/binding.js#L586)

Comment: Thanks it works. Im new to ember (and handlebars) can you explain what is metamorph? By the way i also tried with bind-attr in following way:
<tr {{bind-attr class='table-strips id'}}> i suppose that im doing it wrong.

Comment: Yeah, Ember wraps bound properties with metamorph script tags, that way it can find and replace a single property in the dom without having to redraw the entire dom.  So they are essentially place holders.  When you use unbound it won't inject those place holders because you are telling it I don't plan on updating these properties, so no need to keep track of where they are in the dom.

Comment: I was giving `bind-attr` as an example of code that you could duplicate for your own use, bind-attr doesn't support passing helpers in as one of the parameters.